# Animal condition through religion in "The Stand"

Tags: religion, animals, stephen-king, good-against-evil

After reading the long passage in Stephen King's "The Stand" where the first group of survivors joined Abigail mother, I had the impression that the author played with the contrast between the faith of Abigail and her lack of compassion for the different animals killed for food.

This is even more marked when the vet says that he is "non-violent" and can not kill the pig.

It gives me the feeling that the author has deliberately sought to highlight the animal condition within religions through the manichean and mainstrem battle between good and evil.

Could it be so ?

Comment: since the question is opinion based there cant really be an answer, for what its worth I believe King was just using the scene for some characterization and intended no hidden meaning.